# How to create triangle mesh from list of points in Elm

Tags: elm

Lets say I have a list of points

```
[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ...] or [[p1,p2,p3,...],[...]...]
```

were `p1,p2,p3` are one stripe and `p4,p5,p6` the other.

```
p1 - p4 - p7 ...
 | / |  / |
p2 - p5 - p8 ...
 | / |  / |
p3 - p6 - p9 ...
.    .    .
.    .    .
.    .    .
```

How can I transform this into a list of

```
[(p1,p2,p4), (p4,p5,p2), (p2,p3,p5), (p5,p6,p3), ...]
```

Is there a way without converting the list into an `Array` und use `get` and handle all the `Maybe`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's define how to split a square into two triangles:

```elm
squareToTriangles : a -> a -> a -> a -> List (a, a, a)
squareToTriangles topLeft botLeft topRight botRight =
    [ (topLeft, botLeft, topRight)
    , (topRight, botRight, botLeft)
    ]
```

Now, since squares are made of two lists, let's assume you can use a list of tuples as input. Now you can make triangles out of lists of left/right points:

```elm
triangles : List (a, a) -> List (a, a, a)
triangles list =
    case list of
        (tl, tr) :: ((bl, br) :: _ as rest) ->
            List.append
                (squareToTriangles tl bl tr br)
                (triangles rest)
        _ ->
            []
```

Of course, your input doesn't involve tuples, so let's define something that takes a list of lists as input:

```elm
triangleMesh : List (List a) -> List (a, a, a)
triangleMesh list =
    case list of
        left :: (right :: _ as rest) ->
            List.append
                (triangles <| List.map2 (,) left right)
                (triangleMesh rest)
        _ ->
            []
```

Now you can pass in your list of lists, such that:

```elm
triangleMesh [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
-- yields...
[(1,2,4),(4,5,2),(2,3,5),(5,6,3),(4,5,7),(7,8,5),(5,6,8),(8,9,6)]
```

Note that this can probably be optimized by using a better method than `List.append`, but the general algorithm holds.

Comment: Just one question to understand whats going on here. `(tl, tr) :: ((bl, br) :: _ as rest)` means you get the 2 items from the head of the list and then put back the second back to the list and store as `rest`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pattern match on your list as follows:

```
toMesh: List Float -> List (Float, Float, Float)
toMesh list =
  case list of
    [ p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6] ->
      Just [(p1,p2,p4), (p4,p5,p2), (p2,p3,p5), (p5,p6,p3)]

    _ ->
      []
```

Comment: Lets say my question is a simplified version, so there will be around 500 -1000 points in the list. I'll update the question